# How combine dbSendQuery with values from DataFrame in R?

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I'm looking for a way to include data from an `R` dataframe in a sql predicate. Ideally, I'd like to use `dbSendQuery` from the `RMySQL` package to send a query to my database that contains a `WHERE ... IN` conditions that includes values from my database. Is this possible?

#### Example data frame

```
BUR
LAX
LGB
```

#### Example query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE airport IN ('BUR', 'LAX', 'LGB')
```

Is there a way to "pass" the rows of my data frame to a query? This might not be possible, but I'm interested to know.

Comment: I updated the answer based on a good comment from @hadley. I should have escaped the quotation marks. I also made the code much more concise.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I typically create a "format" string, then sub in the values using `sprintf` and `paste` like below:

```
qformat <- "SELECT * FROM table WHERE airport IN (%s)"
vals <- c("BUR", "LAX", "LGB")

qstring <- sprintf(qformat, paste0("\"", vals, "\"", collapse = ","))
cat(qstring)
# SELECT * FROM table WHERE airport IN ("BUR","LAX","LGB")
```

If you have to do it a lot, just wrap the messy part in a function:

```
someFunc <- function(x) paste0("\"", x, "\"", collapse = ",")
qstring <- sprintf(qformat, someFunc(vals))
```

If you're worried about SQL injection take a look at `?dbEscapeStrings`.

Comment: I'm accepting this as an answer because I know that it will work. It's unfortunate that this type of functionality isn't already implemented in `dbSendQuery`. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Down voting for lack of escaping

Comment: @hadley Looked back at old code and edited the answer to be more concise and correct. Thank you for keeping me honest.

Comment: Escaping still isn't correct, sorry. Google little Bobby tables.